# Why mono is required to debug node application?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code is a good IDE. But...

Why mono is required to debug node application ?
A native debugger can't be used in Visual ?

Node inspector (base on Chrome Dev Tools) is generaly used to debug node applications. It's a native debugger in C++ (I think).

And VSCode work without Mono expect for Debug !

So why this choice ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio Code: Preview currently requres Mono but in the future will depend only on CoreCLR when it is ready.

Comment: Source for this answer?