# Visual Studio Code is attempting to launch Mono instead of Node

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I attempt to debug my Node app from within Visual Studio Code, I receive an error message:

Cannot start OpenDebug because Mono (or a Mono version >= 3.10.0) is required

I have a default launch.json file that specifies that the type of the launch is "node".

I'm using Visual Studio Code v0.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.

All of this had been working a while ago, but just stopped. Between the time that it had been working and now, I've updated Ubuntu a couple of times, but have not changed any environment variables or anything else that I'm aware of that would confuse Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

Currently VSCode requires mono to debug node on non windows platforms.
I think this was previously working because you had mono installed as this behaviour has not changed between versions.
Why mono is required [Why mono is required to debug node application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963939/why-mono-is-required-to-debug-node-application)

How to install mono https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/debugging